# What is it that is bigger than the html tag?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a page like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section id="the-view-port">
```

The height of the section is 100vh

```
#the-view-port { height: 100vh; }
```

In Chrome (Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)) there is something below this in the window. If I right click on that part and inspect it I just get to the html tag.

What is it that is below the html tag? How do I get rid of it?

Hm, and yes there are some more css that might be relevant.

```
box-sizing: border-box; // on html
display: flex // on body
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the margin on the body by user agent stylesheet?

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        body {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;  
        }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <section style="height: 100vh;" id="the-view-port">
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        body {
            display: flex;  
        }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <section style="height: 100vh;" id="the-view-port">
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't thinks so. The margin is set to 0. And the computed style margin is also 0.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself just to clear up. The strange behavior was caused by an `height: inherit` on an inner div. Changing to `height: auto` fixed the problem.

It is not clear to me why clicking on the "overflowing" part led me to the html-tag.

Taking this little quiz reminded me of this pitfall:

https://css-tricks.com/how-well-do-you-know-css-layout/